# Simple PHP and oAuth Library

Tags: php, oauth

I'm looking for a basic oAuth library for PHP, something that I can just pass a consumer key, a secret key, and a URL to request the token, (and a callback) where it will just return an oAuth Token. The main feature it needs is to be useable accross various social networks. currently I have a massive wrapper for Twitter, a massive wrapper for facebook and another for Linked in etc, which could be replaced with one function for each site, and a basic oAuth site.

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/oauth-php/ ,  twitter example : http://code.google.com/p/oauth-php/source/browse/trunk/example/client/twoleggedtwitter.php

Comment: Twitter and Facebook use different versions of OAuth. You can't have support for these two in one library

Comment: I tried to build this. It is available in google code but never finished it. Currently only works for twitter and linkedin http://code.google.com/p/social-php/

Comment: thanks, for the suggestions. Sanmai, I realise they use different versions of oAuth, but all I wanted was a genereic sign in class and I was going to build the rest myself. I was having problems signing the request.
Roel, that's exactly what I'm looking for, but I found an alternative before I saw your post.

https://github.com/jrconlin/oauthsimple/blob/master/php/example.php
is a simple oAuth Library. There's also oAuth built into PHP, which I only discovered last night!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are no such library at the moment. You have the [oauth-php](http://code.google.com/p/oauth-php/) and [oauth2-php](http://code.google.com/p/oauth2-php/) library but they're not "simple", the good part is they manage their token themselves.
They don't like overlong tokens (like Yahoo's) which can be a big problem.

Also, some functions of the Microsoft API are not available in their 5.0 version anymore, meaning you have to use their old API which implement their [own Oauth protocol](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff750690.aspx) (all oauth_* parameters are named wrap_*).

Edit: you can check the [HybridAuth](http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net/) project which implements the login part (not the whole APIs) but should give you a good starter.

Comment: I'll check out HybridAuth tonight, looks like the closest I'm going to get

Comment: Turns out there's oAuth built into PHP, which is simpler than the suggestions.
https://github.com/jrconlin/oauthsimple/blob/master/php/example.php was a good example I found of an easy oAuth library, but in the end I went for HybridAuth. It deals with the logins, which was exactly what I wanted, I can build the rest of the API on top of it (I don't need a whole lot more)
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I actually came across this question myself and ended up building an OAuth library after looking at all the choices I had. Here's some sample code for calling Twitter's API:

```
use ohmy\Auth1;

# start a session to save oauth data in-between redirects
session_start();

# initialize 3-legged oauth
$twitter = Auth1::init(3);

# configuration
$twitter->set('key', 'your consumer key')
        ->set('secret', 'your consumer secret')
        ->set('callback', 'your callback url')
        ->request('https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token')
        ->authorize('https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize')
        ->access('https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token')
        ->finally(session_destroy);

# test GET call
$twitter->GET('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/home_timeline.json', array('count' => 5))
        ->then(function($response) {
            echo '<pre>';
            var_dump($response->json());
            echo '</pre>';
        });
```

The library works with Twitter, Facebook, and LinkedIn. You can check it out at: https://github.com/sudocode/ohmy-auth